# What happens with Inserts if SQLite Database reaches storage limit?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I have a mobile app (iOS/Android) which uses a SQLite Database. If I insert data the database grow to a point where the maximal allowed limit is reached. When the database reaches its limit and I insert new data what will happen with this data?

Edit:

What max quota do I have on iOS and Android?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#full

Answer (score 1):

Your data won't be inserted as your DB is full, and you'll get a SQLITE_FULL error.

To learn about limits of SQLite please go here:
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

It seems quite unlikely that you'll reach that limit.

You can set a logical limit manually, and set the behavior of it (for example, 100 entries maximum and if 101 is added, delete the oldest one)

Comment: Could you please post an example of how to set the limit manually and overwrite the oldest entry?